# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar mi bot de Discord Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Tengo un bot de Discord hecho en en el que lo ejecuto desde mi PC, pero ya me da algo de pereza estar realizando esto constantemente o que requiera de los recursos de mi PC. Así que quisiera saber como podría alquirar un servidor o algún hosting que ejecute mi código y mi bot pueda funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios servicios gratuitos para poder alojar tu proyecto:

PythonAnywhere:
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Heroku:
https://www.heroku.com/

Amazon AWS:
https://aws.amazon.com/es/

O te puedes crear tu propio servidor en tu PC, pero tendrá que estar siempre encendido, y crearte un subdominio con alguna herramienta como DuckDNS.

Yo por ejemplo, mis projectos antes de subirlos a algún servidor, los subo primero a una Raspberry Pi que tengo.

Comment: Para los nuevos usuarios leyendo esta respuesta, [Heroku ya no es una opción gratuita](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2502)